# Grouping tuples of 2 numbers based on the difference between the tuples

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tuples

| Serial Number | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parameter 1 | 22.95 | 23.46 | 22.71 | 23.41 | 23.36 | 23.18 | 23.52 | 23.35 | 22.86 | 22.47 | 22.63 | 23.72 | 23.22 | 23.17 | 22.8 | 23.18 | 23.15 | 23.12 | 23.16 | 23.22 | 23.58 | 23.68 | 23.33 | 23.52 | 23.54 | 23.48 |
| Parameter 2 | 19.97 | 20.83 | 19.22 | 20.39 | 20.33 | 20.44 | 20.62 | 20.26 | 21.22 | 20.31 | 20.53 | 20.62 | 20.65 | 20.14 | 19.43 | 20.66 | 20.09 | 20.52 | 20.41 | 20.63 | 20.98 | 21.15 | 19.97 | 20.72 | 20.71 | 20.32 |

We have to divide this table into groups of 4 columns such that:-

1.Max difference between the values of parameter 1 of the columns in a group is less than 1

2.Max difference between the values parameter 2 of the columns in a group is less than 0.5

for eg. The columns 4,5,6,7 form a valid group

I need an algorithm that will return the maximum number of groups that this table can be divided into and will also return those groups.

for eg. In this case the maximum number of groups possible are 6, and the remaining 2 columns do not fall under any group. The algorithm should return these 6 groups.

Comment: This isn't quite a question, more of a problem statement.

Comment: I agree, but I need this algorithm for a problem in my company.